# MySql Queries Stop After Calling Stored Procedure on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've a really basic PHP code that parse and returns the table from a stored procedure. It's all working fine on Mysql side, but when I call it with mysql_query, the queries after that lines basically stops and returns null value.

```
mysql_query("call sp_test()");
```

If I include the code above, all the other mysql queries stops, but that one works perfectly. What I'm missing? I can't use PDO mysqli in my project so I need a solution with mysql_query.

Comment: It's really difficult to provide any meaningful answer, since the error description is quite vague. Have you tried simplifying sp_test() stored procedure to do sg very simple to verify if it's the call to any stored procedure that causes the issue or it's only that particular stored procedure you have that causes the issue?

Comment: sp_test procedure only includes only "select 'a' as a" kind of test select query. There's no error description, it's just simple as I described, if I use the line in my php it basically stop mysql connection. I also tried to call that function in footer, it loaded every mysql query correctly, except function after that didn't returned any value.